# How to calculate or verify card shuffling get the proper probability?

Tags: probability

In computer programming, we often have a problem such as to shuffle 52 cards, like a deck of playing cards.

For simplicity, let's consider only 3 cards here.  One simple algorithm is (I think it is called Knuth's Shuffle, which is very close to Fisher–Yates shuffle):

> (Method 1) from the pile of 3 (or 52) cards in sorted order (in the order 1, 2, 3), pick one out at random, and put into a new pile. Repeat this step until all cards are moved to the new pile.

Note that to save memory space and make the program run faster, the standard solution is not really to use a new array (not to use a new pile), but to swap the numbers in the original array. This has the same effect, except (1) no new memory needs to be allocated. (2) no overhead need to be done to delete or insert the element in the new or old array, which is time consuming. (and the running time is what programmer called O(n<sup>2</sup>) instead of O(n), because O(n<sup>2</sup>) means quadratic run time, meaning when n is 50, O(n) indicates 50 steps, and O(n<sup>2</sup>) means 2500 steps).

This one is quite easy to calculate / verify:

What is the chance of that particular card get to the bottom of the new stack?  1/3, because we choose 1 card out of 3 at random.  What about for the 2nd card to get to where it is?  P(not picked the first time) x P(picked the second time) = 2/3 x 1/2 = 1/3. Likewise, for the 3rd card: P(not pick 1st time) x P(not picked the 2nd time) x P(picked the 3rd time) = 2/3 x 1/2 x 1/1 = 1/3.

So it is evenly distributed.  We can do that if it is 52 cards, and for the 4th card: 51/52 x 50/51 x 49 / 50 x 1 / 49 = 1/52.

Now however, in Rebert Sedgewick's video that accompanied his Algorithms book, he proposed a different method (the method is by swapping, and the method below is a little different from his method in the video, and is by inserting):

> (Method 2) from the pile of 3 cards in sorted order (in the order 1, 2, 3), pick the top card, and choose a random position to insert into the new pile. Now when the pile is empty, you can only place it on the table. For the 2nd card, pick it from the top of the old pile, and insert it at a random position in the new pile (meaning at the bottom or all the way to the top). Repeat until all cards are done.

Now how do we calculate the probability and show that each card get a proper probability (evenly distributed)? Especially for 52 cards, once a card get to a position in the new stack, it can get moved up or down in the new stack.

Now the 3rd method, which is known to be *wrong*, which is similar to method 1, but:

> (Method 3) spread out the 3 (or 52) cards. Now for card 1, swap it with any random card (including itself). And now repeat for card 2, and repeat until the last card is done.  So in the example of 52 cards, swap card 1 with card i, where i is a random number from 1 to 52. For card 2, swap it with card j, where j is a random number from 1 to 52. Repeat until the end.

This one above, it can be shown to have an uneven distribution, but I don't know how to calculate it to show that it is wrong.

If I run a program for a million times, the distribution is something like this:

```
{[3, 2, 1]=>148157, [3, 1, 2]=>148242, [1, 3, 2]=>184486, [2, 3, 1]=>186036, 
 [1, 2, 3]=>147948, [2, 1, 3]=>185131}
```

and it is not even. For it to be even, it should be something like this:

```
{[2, 1, 3]=>167090, [1, 2, 3]=>166380, [1, 3, 2]=>166927, [2, 3, 1]=>166451, 
 [3, 2, 1]=>166174, [3, 1, 2]=>166978}
```

If you are interested: the standard Knuth's shuffle, by swapping, is similar to Method 3 above, except it is:

> (Method 1 by swapping) spread out the 3 (or 52) cards, now for card 1, swap it with any random card (including itself). And now, don't ever touch card 1 any more (treating it as a new pile of card and never touch it). And now repeat for card 2, swap it with any remaining card (from card 2 to card 3 (or card 52). Repeat until the end. This has the same effect of Method 1 above, which is to use 2 piles of cards: the original pile and the new pile.

Actually Sedgewick's method has 2 variations.  One is what I described above. But the original method in his video is also by swapping: Say, for 52 cards, then for the 10th card, he actually swap it with the k<sup>th</sup> card, where k is a random number from 1 to 10  (we are using base index 1 here), so he doesn't insert it at a random position but his method actually is to swap it with the k<sup>th</sup> card (and he does it for card 2 to card 52). I wrote both versions as computer programs and they both turned out to be evenly distributed. It is somewhat strange that in Sedgewick's video, he labeled his method as Knuth Shuffle, when Knuth Shuffle should be Method 1.

Comment: See “The bias of three pseudorandom shuffles” (Ethan Bolker and  David Robbins), AequationesMathematicae, 22, 1981, 268-292

Comment: @EthanBolker unfortuntely I don't have easy access to a university library for that material. And I realized you are the author. What an honor. So far, I haven't seen an explanation that is understandable by a grade 9 or 10 student. I think I can explain most concepts in math, such as log, trigonometry, differentiation, integration, to a grade 9 student, but this uneven distribution, I can't understand it and can't explain to a 15 year old

Answer (score 1):

To show that method 3 is wrong, consider the parity of the permutation generated. If the card swaps with itself, that doesn't change the parity. If it swaps with any other card, it changes the parity. The first case happens with probability $1/N$, and the second with probability $(N-1)/N$, so the probability of performing exactly $k$ parity swaps is
$$
P(k) = \binom{N}{k}\frac{(N-1)^k}{N^N}.
$$
The difference in probability between an even number of swaps and an odd number of swaps is then
$$
P(+) - P(-) = \sum_{k=0}^N (-1)^k\binom{N}{k}\frac{(N-1)^k}{N^N} = \frac{1}{N^N}\sum_{k=0}^N \binom{N}{k}(1-N)^k \\= \frac{(1-N+1)^N}{N^N} = (-1)^N\left(1-\frac{2}{N}\right)^N
$$
For $N = 3$, this says that odd permutations should happen $1/27$ of the time more often than even permutations. In your data, the odd permutations $[1,3,2]$, $[3,2,1]$, and $[2,1,3]$ occurred $35548$ more often than the even permutations $[1,2,3]$, $[2,3,1]$, and $[3,1,2]$, consistent with $10^6/27 \approx 37037$. For large $N$, the difference in the probabilities will approach $1/e^2 \approx 1/7.4$

Comment: is there an easy way to show that Method 2 is correct?

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Perhaps by induction? Show that if it generates a uniform distribution of permutations for $n$ cards, then it also generates a uniform distribution of perturbations for $n+1$ cards.

Comment: I was thinking about the same thing: that it can be calculated that for 2 cards only, it is even distribution, and then for having 1 more card, it is again, and then for k vs k + 1... although, it is good as a proof, but maybe there is a way to directly show that it is true.  For proving Method 3 is wrong, you use parity. Is it some kind of probability theory about parity and how it is related to even distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd like to use a more direct method, induction can be used to prove that Method 2 and its variation can achieve even distribution.

For the case of 2 cards, it is easy to establish, and for the case of 3 cards, it is easy to base on the 2 card scenario and reach the result of even distribution.

Let's try to do it for a more general case of 22 cards already properly shuffled, with even distribution.

(the following index is 1 based:)

Variation 1: inserting a 23rd card into any where in the pile of 22 cards.  Then for any card in the resultant pile, let's say for the 10th card. What is the probability that it reaches the 10th position? It is P(it landed on position 9 and the newly inserted card is inserted before it) + P(it landed on position 10 and the newly inserted card is inserted after it) = 1/22 x 9/23 + 1/22 x 13/23 = 1/22 x (9/23 + 13/23) = 1/22 x 22/23 = 1/23.  The newly inserted card also has even probability to become position 1 to 23.

Let's also see the case for 2 cards already shuffled with even distribution and the 3rd card being inserted. What is the probability that the card became card 2? It is P(it landed on position 1 and the newly inserted card is inserted before it) + P(it landed on position 2 and the newly inserted card is inserted after it) = 1/2 x 1/3 + 1/2 x 1/3 = 1/2 x (1/3 + 1/3) = 1/3.

Variation 2: swapping card 23 with card i where i is 1 to 23.  Then again, for any card in the resultant pile, let's say for the 10th card. What is the probability that it reaches the 10th position?  It is P(it landed on position 10) x P(it did not get swapped away) = 1/22 x 22/23 = 1/23. Again, the 23rd card that get swapped in has even probability to become card 1 to 23.

So it is again even. And we can establish for 24 cards, 25 cards, and for N cards in general with N ≥ 1.